# Change BuildConfig file in Android Studio using Gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-buildconfig

I am trying to add URL into my `BuildConfig` file using Gradle in [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/). So I added this code into the `gradle` file

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        buildConfigField "String", "MIDTRANS_API", '"https://app.sandbox.midtrans.com/snap/v1"'
    }
}
```

Then I tried to rebuild my project and hoped that this value will appear in `BuildConfig` file, but it was not so. Can someone explain how to do this correctly?

My complete `gradle` file code is as below

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        buildConfigField "String", "DAR_API", '"{some string}"'
        buildConfigField "String", "DAR_API_AUTH", '"{some string}"'
        buildConfigField "String", "MIDTRANS_API", '"https://app.sandbox.midtrans.com/snap/v1"'
    }

    rc {
        minifyEnabled true
        debuggable true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        buildConfigField "String", "DAR_API", '"{some string}"'
    }

    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        buildConfigField "String", "DAR_API", '"{some string}"'
    }
}
```

After that goes dependencies, but I think it is not related to problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField "String", "MIDTRANS_API", "\"https://app.sandbox.midtrans.com/snap/v1\""
        }
        release {
            buildConfigField "String", "MIDTRANS_API", "\"https://app.sandbox.midtrans.com/snap/v1\""
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

In Java you can access this by the below code after synchronising the Gradle files.

```
String url = BuildConfig.MIDTRANS_API
```

Comment: Should I add this field into release in order to see this field in `BuildConfig` file? Because I cannot access to it as you stated in answer

Comment: You should rebuild your project probably in order to add filed in ```BuildConfig```

Comment: You know, actually I had other field in `BuildConfig` and I changed its value from `gradle` and made rebuild of project but it still did not changed, why?

Comment: Paste your complete gradle file. There must be something that you are doing wrong.

Comment: Or you can do this. ```File -> Invalidate Cache / Restart``` then click on invalidae and restart. Android studio will restart and if you have written everything right then you will be able to get fields in buildconfig

Comment: what if I will add this fields by my own into `BuildConfig` file?

Comment: I see, you are writing some libaray. Please remember that you can't access buildConfigs of libaray into app module. That's impossible.

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: you required fields in app or in libaray module?

Comment: in app module, I tried it to put in app gradle file and rebuild, but still same problem

Comment: You must be using wrong buildConfig file. When you import BuildConfig make sure it match with the package name of your app module.

Comment: Thank you, it should be added to other `gradle` file

Comment: glad that it helped, no problem.

Comment: @ZeeshanShabbir "When you import BuildConfig make sure it match with the package name of your app module." My import was not correct. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the same buildConfigField property in my project and I was successfully able to see it under **BuildConfig** file for debug variant.

Probably your project didn't rebuild properly. Try cleaning the project and then build it again.

To fetch the property value in your Java code, you'll have to do this:

```
String API_URL = BuildConfig.MIDTRANS_API;
```

Note: **In order to access this property in release build you would have to copy it under release type as well. Then change the Build Variant to release.**

In your gradle file do this,

```
buildTypes {

    debug {
        buildConfigField "String", "MIDTRANS_API", '"https://app.sandbox.midtrans.com/snap/v1"'
    }

    release {
        buildConfigField "String", "MIDTRANS_API", "https://app.sandbox.midtrans.com/snap/v1"
    }
}
```

This should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by changing the package name in the `manifest.xml` file which still hadn't been updated:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          package="com.example.android">
```